# How do I calculate the Cumulative probability Function without the use of scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, formula

I Meant

```
x1 = 0
cdf = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x1)
```

What is the raw mathematical formula to calculate the CDF that includes the mean and variance? (withotu using numpy, matplotlib etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want:

```
from math import erf, sqrt

def cdf(x):
    return (1 + erf(x/sqrt(2))) / 2

x1 = 0
```

```
>>> cdf(x1)
0.5
```

Read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516435/mean-and-variance-from-a-cumulative-distribution-function) on MathExchange:

Comment: I don't understand why  (1 + erf(x/sqrt(2))) / 2 is the formula for CDF. Isn't CDF just every iteration of a PDF added together?